# How can I merge these functions into a single function with attributes?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to merge these functions into a single function where I can pass two attributes, form and field.

```
_last_name(){
  this.refs.patient.refs.input.refs.last_name.refs.input.focus()
},
_phone(){
  this.refs.contact.refs.input.refs.phone.refs.input.focus()
},
_email(){
  this.refs.contact.refs.input.refs.email.refs.input.focus()
},
_street_address(){
  this.refs.contact.refs.input.refs.street_address.refs.input.focus()
},
_suite_or_apt(){
  this.refs.contact.refs.input.refs.suite_or_apt.refs.input.focus()
},
_city(){
  this.refs.contact.refs.input.refs.city.refs.input.focus()
},
_state(){
  this.refs.contact.refs.input.refs.state.refs.input.focus()
},
_zipcode(){
  this.refs.contact.refs.input.refs.zipcode.refs.input.focus()
},
```

I've tried this, but It doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
_focus_on(form, field){
  this.refs.form.refs.input.refs.field.refs.input.focus()
}
```

I think it's just a syntax problem.

Comment: In order to acces a object property by name you need to use "bracket notation". So `foo.bar` translates to `foo['bar']`. Now instead of `'bar'` you can pass a variable. In your case it'd be `this.refs[form].refs.input.refs[field].refs.input.focus()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it. If you use bracket notation (`obj[field]`) you can access the properties of an object using variables.

```
_focus_on(form, field) {
  this.refs[form].refs.input.refs[field].input.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
_focusOn(form, field){
  this.refs[form].refs.input.refs[field].refs.input
}
```